# Unit Testing - How to test long running external processes

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a method which calls another a method from another class which in turn executes numerous private methods within the second class. One method writes a file which is then picked up by an external process, the external process runs between 5 to 30 mins depending on what needs processed, another file is then produced which is picked up by my application which reads it and returns data into the initial method which was called.

I know what I described is not a "Unit" but the method is public, so my question is what would I need to test in this method and how could I mock the call to the method within the second class?  Or do I just let the method run normally whether it be 5 mins or 30 mins?

```
class A
{
    public List<DataClass> MethodUnderTest()
    {
        List<string> requiredData;
        SecondClass B = New SecondClass();
        requiredData = B.GenerateFile();
        //B.GenerateFile() Executes a number of private methods within the SecondClass, 
        //This can be treated as a service call.  This runs between 5 and 30 mins
        return requiredData.Select(r => new DataClass{
                                     Property1 = r.Substring(0,2),
                                     Property2 = r.Substring(3,5),
                                     Property3 = r.Substring(9,10)
                                     }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Way too many concerns happening here. What are you ultimately trying to test? If the classes involved we designed SOLID-ly you should be to substitute dependencies for the unit test. Based on the description this smell of a lot of tight coupling.

Comment: I'm not the original developer for the SecondClass and not the way I would of coded it but it is what I am stuck with. I ultimately want to test that the B.GenerateFile return a List<string> that I can then parse into a List<DataClass>

Comment: If you are not actually trying to unit test SecodClass then treat SecondClass as 3rd party and abstract it behind code you control. That way you are able to isolate your code and properly maintain/test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat `SecondClass` as 3rd party dependency and encapsulate it behind code you control. Create an abstraction of the functionality you want from the dependency;

```
public interface ISecondClass {
    List<string> GenerateFile();
}
```

Class A also has too many concerns and should remove any responsibilities/concerns that do not belong to class A.

```
public interface IDataClassParser {
    DataClass Parse(string data);
}

public class DefaultDataClassParser : IDataClassParser {
    public DataClass Parse(string data) {
        return new DataClass {
            Property1 = data.Substring(0, 2),
            Property2 = data.Substring(3, 5),
            Property3 = data.Substring(9, 10)
        };
    }
}
```

The above is a naive example for demonstration purposes.

Refactor the target class to now explicitly depend on the abstraction and not on the concretion.

```
public class A {
    private readonly ISecondClass B;
    private readonly IDataClassParser parser;

    public A(ISecondClass B, IDataClassParser parser) {
        this.B = B;
        this.parser = parser;
    }

    public List<DataClass> MethodUnderTest() {
        List<string> requiredData = B.GenerateFile();
        return requiredData.Select(createNewDataClass).ToList();
    }

    private DataClass createNewDataClass(string r) {
        return parser.Parse(r);
    }
}
```

Class `A` is no longer tightly coupled to implementation concerns and now the method under test can be tested in isolation.

Example test

```
[TestClass]
public class ATest {
    [TestMethod]
    public void MethodUnderTest_Should_Return_DataClassList() {
        //Arrange
        List<string> mockData = new List<string>();
        //TODO: Populate mockData
        var mockB = new Mock<ISecondClass>();
        mockB.Setup(_ => _.GenerateFile()).Returns(mockData);

        var sut = new A(mockB.Object, new DefaultDataClassParser());

        //Act
        var actual = sut.MethodUnderTest();

        //Assert
        //TODO: assert that the actual result satisfies expectations
    }        
}
```

Technically the above is now only actually testing the parser and thus an additional test can be written to test the parsing code in isolation.

```
[TestClass]
public class DataClassParserTest {
    [TestMethod]
    public void DataClassParser_Should_Return_DataClass() {
        //Arrange
        string mockData = "..."; //TODO: Populate mockData
        var sut = new DefaultDataClassParser();

        //Act
        var actual = sut.Parse(mockData);

        //Assert
        //TODO: assert that the actual result satisfies expectations
    }        
}
```

Finally, in production, the implementation of your long running class would derive from the abstraction and encapsulate the dependent `SecondClass`

```
public class SecondClassWrapper : ISecondClass {
    private SecondClass B = new SecondClass();
    public List<string> GenerateFile() {
        return B.GenerateFile();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you kind of answered your own question, but I will outline what I would do: Create a interface for SecondClass and depend on that (you will need to inject that dependency (any way you like)), then I would mock its behavior in the unit tests. For that moq would do the job. That levs us with what logic to test: well the only interesting thin going on is the substring stuff - so test that. Then you will need to visit the SecondClass and see what unit test you can create there.

What about unit and non unit test? I say you need both, but you will execute them different (where unit should be run every time you change the code on your machine (so, they need to execute fast (hence mock is key here) like a few k in ms), and the integration/functional tests that will execute all dependencies on commit (normally on a build server). And they will take more time (in your case at least 30s to a few m) but that is fine since they do not run as often.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to determine how to unit test a method of a class (`A`) that invokes a method of another class (`SecondClass`). The method that you're testing doesn't do much. For the most part it will work if the the method it invokes works. So that (`GenerateFile`) is the best place to focus on writing tests.

You mentioned that `SecondClass` invokes a number of private methods. How complex are those methods? I'm guessing (and I could be way off) that some of them are rather complex because the method that calls them takes so long to run. If the small tasks that make up that long-running process is tested then your process is a composition of tested methods or classes.

If those private methods are complex then you can't really test them by testing a method that calls a method that calls those methods. Perhaps some of the behavior of those private methods can be placed in separate classes, which can themselves be unit tested.

It sounds like a lot of moving things around, but in order to get the benefit of testing we have to write code which can be tested. That changes the way we write code, and usually for the better.

Going back to the method you originally asked about:
You have a method that takes a `List<string>` and converts it to a  `List<DataClass>`. For simplicity, why not write a method that converts a `string` to a `DataClass`? Perhaps you could put that in an extension or even in its own class.

```
DataClass FromString(string input)
{
    return new DataClass{
        Property1 = r.Substring(0,2),
        Property2 = r.Substring(3,5),
        Property3 = r.Substring(9,10)
    }
}
```

Then you can test that method to make sure that a `DataClass` parsed from a string has the expected property values. And your previous statement becomes so simple that it hardly even needs a test of its own.

```
return requiredData.Select(r => FromString(r)).ToList();
```

As was suggested in another answer, `SecondClass` should ideally be an interface on which `A` depends. But even if it's not, if `SecondClass` is itself unit tested well then `MethodUnderTest` is going to be sound because it's doing nothing except calling one tested method and passing the result to another tested method.

But if you do replace `SecondClass` with an interface then `MethodUnderTest` becomes super easy to test because you just use a "test double", a simple implementation for test purposes only that's hard coded to return the values that you want to test. So your test is effectively saying, "Assuming that `ISecondClass` returns these values, I expect `MethodUnderTest` to return these values." And it won't take minutes to run, only milliseconds.

Even if all of the pieces are tested, it makes sense that you'd still want an integration test that runs the whole thing end-to-end. Can you create a small file with less data and run your test against that?